# Move LineRenderer with its parent in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity and I'm create LineRenderers as children of a GameObject named "out100". I can move this GameObject with a mouse scroll click, rotate it with a right click etc... But it's only the GameObject "out100" that moves and not the LineRenderers.

**How can I adjust the code below to get the LineRenderers to move with the GameObject "out100"?**

Code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Vector3>> sl in d) 
{
    Color c1 = Color.yellow;
    Color c2 = Color.red;
    GameObject lines = new GameObject ();
    lines.name = "lines" + sl.Key;
    lines.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
    lines.transform.SetParent (GameObject.Find ("out100").transform);
    LineRenderer lineRenderer = lines.GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
    lineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Particles/Additive"));
    lineRenderer.widthMultiplier = 0.2f;
    lineRenderer.positionCount = sl.Value.Count;
    float alpha = 1.0f;
    Gradient gradient = new Gradient ();
    gradient.SetKeys 
    (
        new GradientColorKey[] { new GradientColorKey (c1, 0.0f), new GradientColorKey (c2, 1.0f) },
        new GradientAlphaKey[] { new GradientAlphaKey (alpha, 0.0f), new GradientAlphaKey (alpha, 1.0f) }
    );
    lineRenderer.colorGradient = gradient;
    lineRenderer.GetComponent<LineRenderer> ().SetPositions (sl.Value.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Set the line renderer to use local space in the inspector.

Comment: Ok thanks you it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to uncheck use world space

[image: use world space]